# Pine Script getting the number of bars in a position

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to have a static stop loss based on the swing low at the entry time. but when i tried the following, the stop loss kept changing with every bar as there are new lowest lows

```
SwingLowBars=20

longStop = lowest(low, SwingLowBars)[1]

longTake = strategy.position_avg_price + ((strategy.position_avg_price-longStop)*3)
```

i want a function that keeps adding +1 to the SwingLowBars variable with every new candle in the position so that the longTake stays static and doesn't change when the lowest bar is more than 20 bars away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can memorize the SL value in "var" variable:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

SwingLowBars=20
longStop = lowest(low, SwingLowBars)[1]
var sl = float(na)
if strategy.position_size !=0 and strategy.position_size[1] == 0
    sl := strategy.position_avg_price - ((strategy.position_avg_price-longStop)*3)
    
strategy.exit("x", stop = sl)
```